# Display three random images at the same time in angular

Tags: angularjs

Please I would like to know how I could display three (3) random images when a button is clicked on using Angular.

Thank you

Comment: This question is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a model list for the listing image:
   Ex:

var imageList = [{"id" : 1, "ImagesUrl" :"http....."}, {"id" : 1, "ImagesUrl" :"http....."} ...]

2. Using function Radom on js :

   function get_random (list) {
   return list[Math.floor((Math.random()*list.length))];
   }
3. Display to Html

Comment: ok, I will try that. thanks

Comment: Please look at my code and I cannot get the images display randomly when I clicked the button: